# copying mongodb data from VM to AWS instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have mongodb running on one of the VM internally. Now, we are moving the service on  AWS.

How should I transport the mongodb data from VM to  AWS instance? Mongo is running inside docker container in AWS.

Should I use MongoDump and MongoRestore? or any other approach here?

Also, I don't see mongod running as a service on AWS instance, since they are running inside the docker container. So, should I need to install the mongodb package and then do mongorestore?

Any help or thoughts here?

Comment: Mongodump, copy file, mongorestore. `mongod` needs to be running obviously, but if you can connect to the database then you just aren't looking in the right place for the `mongod` process. As long as you can connect then you should be able to run the restore.